# Part time staff being paid less than full time staff but part time staff doing more work - Legal (UK)?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

My wife is a teacher at a private school in the UK.

After having children she went part time. She's since asked to go full time but has been refused on the basis that they don't have a need for her to be full time.

The way she get's paid is they calculate how many hours of a full time equivalent she does (for example 22 teaching hours would be full time) and she is paid for how many hours she is required to do (e.g. 19 hours).
Therefore she get's paid 86% of a full time equivalent.

Now the school, to be fair is a little over resourced, and the full time staff in her department are teaching less than 19 hours (86%) a week but being paid their full time salary.

She is therefore being paid less to do a greater job than her peers.
Are there any laws being broken here that we can use to convince her school to bump her up to full time and therefore share the hours evenly?

Comment: maybe the system can drop the pay of the full time group and make it very fair.

Comment: @TigerGuy how does that help my wife get her full time job back?

Comment: I thought the issue was fairness.

Comment: The lack of fairness is what drives her to want to do something about it, but if the only solution was others having a pay reduction then that doesn't benefit anyone.

Comment: My point (poorly made) is that if you make a fairness argument, be careful of what the potential solutions might be.